# Can't see files in explorer.exe that were copied from linux

Tags: linux, windows, files, explorer

I copied a few files over from a linux NAS device to an external drive using windows 2003. 
On the external drive, explorer.exe will not show these files, however if you mouse over the folder before entering it, it does list the files.

I also used cygwin to change the permissions to 777 which doesnt help, windows show hidden files is enabled.

any help?

Answer (score 0):

What filesystem are you using on the external hard drive (commonly FAT-32) ? You can find this out by right-clicking on the drive and selecting properties.

Try entering DOS mode Start->Run then enter "cmd" and having a look on the drive.

```
cd e:\
dir /ah
```

will show you any hidden files for instance. Do the files have strange filenames or anything weird like that? Sometimes the filename cannot be properly displayed but you can see it in DOS mode maybe if the filenames are very long.

Do the files appear if you access the drive from another computer? Try booting up with a knoppix CD if you can.

Comment: I resolved this by installing filezilla FTP server/client on my local machine and copying the files one directory higher. 

They were visible through aany browser other than explorer, so i dont know what caused it.